# Gzip and rename issue

Tags: bash, compression, gunzip

I'm trying to decompress a gz file and rename it. The issue is that the file has size 0 after doing it:

```bash
var1="imdb"
var2="gz"
var3="tsv"
gzip -d --no-name "/tmp/${var1}.${var2}" > "tmp/${var1}.${var3}
```

After this I check `ls -l /tmp` and get the following

```
777642064 imdb
0         imdb.tsv
```

I tried the same with the following, it works but then it uses a random name:

gzip -d --name "/tmp/${var1}.${var2}"

```
777642064   randoname.tsv
```

Comment: @markp-fuso, please post your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to force `gzip` to write the decompressed data to stdout (`-c`) and then redirect stdout to the desired file, eg:

```
gzip -d -c "/tmp/${var1}.${var2}" > "/tmp/${var1}.${var3}"
```

**NOTE:** this will leave the original zipped (`.gz`) file in place